# Google Maps API and JQuery Slide Toggle not working together

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please kindly have a look at the following:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/witold/UjdZr/)

It contains a div box that I want to minimize/restore by clicking on it.  In Jsfiddle, it works as expected.

However, when I try to overlay it on a Google Map, something is braking.  SlideToggle() is not working any more.  [Here is the page](http://pollster.net/app7.html) where I am trying to use the Jsfiddle.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Here is the javascript in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "+"){
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the javascript to right before the `</body>` tag, and it works.